# Local apt repository skipping packages

Tags: apt, repository, localrepository

I've created an apt repository for a few local files, generally obscure drivers or locally-created files for my own use. The repository is limited to my own internal network, so it can have non-free files and so on. The repository has worked well for years; too well, perhaps, as I've forgotten exactly how it's set up. I have a directory set up as follows:

```
dists
dists/stable
dists/stable/local/binary-i386
dists/stable/local/binary-amd64
dists/stable/local/binary-all
dists/stable/games/binary-i386
dists/stable/games/binary-amd64
dists/stable/games/binary-all
dists/stable/local
dists/stable/games
pool
pool/local
pool/games
```

Long ago, I wrote a script that runs the following commands:

```
apt-ftparchive generate /etc/apt/apt-ftparchive.conf
apt-ftparchive -c /etc/apt/apt-release.conf release dists/stable > dists/stable/Release
cat /var/www/repopw | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --sign -bao dists/stable/Release.gpg dists/stable/Release
```

If I move or delete files within the repository, or copying files into it from other repositories, I can run the script and the changes show up. However, the files I want to add don't seem to be recognized. They are in the directory, and available if I point a browser at them; they just don't seem to be found by apt-ftparchive. They install fine on my system, so I know they at least work.

I'm fine with using a different tool, as long as it is as simple as putting the file in the directory and running a simple script; there aren't enough files to put much more effort than that in it.

The files I'm attempting to add are Brother printer drivers, found [here](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2360dw_us&os=128):

```
brgenml1cupswrapper-3.1.0-1.i386.deb
brgenml1lpr-3.1.0-1.i386.deb
hll2360dcupswrapper-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
hll2360dlpr-3.2.0-1.i386.deb
```